# Meaning of "Detaching after fork from child process 15***"?

Tags: c, process, gdb

What does it mean when GDB outputs the message above?

> Detaching after fork from child process 15***

Answer (score 62, accepted):

When GDB is debugging a particular process, and the process forks off a child process, GDB can only follow one of the two processes, so it must detach (stop following) the other. This line informs you of this selective detachment. The child process will run without being debugged by GDB.

You can select which process to follow using the `set follow-fork-mode` command. Use `set follow-fork-mode child` to follow child processes, and `set follow-fork-mode parent` to return to the default behavior. For more details, see [this page](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/DeveloperTools/gdb/gdb/gdb_5.html) on the Apple development website.

Comment: I'd be remiss if I didn't add to this comment that GDB doesn't have to pick one any more, and from what I can tell haven't had to for quite some time. `set detach-on-fork off` will make GDB debug both fork parent and fork child.

Why this option is not default in GDB, is beyond me.